# Программная реализация I2C шины через расширитель портов

Tags: c, arduino, микроконтроллеры, esp8266, gpio

Есть:

- МК (Ардуино или Esp8266)
- 8 расширителей портов `MCP23017`
- 8 датчиков влажности `HTU21D` с интерфейсом I2C.

У расширителей портов есть возможность менять адрес в I2C шине используя перемычки A0-A2 и они подключаются к одной общей шине с Мастером (Ардуино или Esp8266). У датчиков влажности такого функционала нет, у них одинаковый адрес. Можно ли подключить датчики влажности с интерфейсом I2C к расширителю портов по GPIO и программно реализовать шину I2C.

**Необходимо с МК получить доступ к данным датчиков влажности через расширитель портов. Как это реализовать?**

Теоретическая схема такого подключения.
[image]

Comment: Мне кажется, вот здесь http://www.bizkit.ru/2019/02/20/12466/ довольно подробно описано подключение разных датчиков через MCP23017 к Arduino. А обязательно использовать HTU21D ? Обычным DHT22 не обойтись?

Comment: У _DHT22_ точность ужасная. И из-за высокой деградации сенсора влажности, датчик через 1-1.5 года подлежит замене.

Comment: В даташите на HTU21 (https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/1899_HTU21D.pdf)  написано, что I2C адрес фиксированный - 0x40. Так что придётся вам к каждому датчику прилеплять какой-то преобразователь адреса... :-(

Comment: Я думаю решить эту проблему следующим образом:
Все датчики влажности я ставлю на одну I2C шину, но питание к ним буду давать от пина из расширителя портов. В итоге для сбора информации я буду обращаться к одному I2C адресу но перед этим переключать питание к датчикам через расширитель портов, будет включен только один датчик в одно и тоже время.

Comment: Интересная идея! Я порылся в иНете, но ничего более подходящего не нашёл...

Comment: @zRirez Может быть поздно, но ... Лучше обрывать не питание датчика, а шину данных к нему (SDA)